# PHP - For each loop problems

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, meta-boxes

In Wordpress I'm trying to create a metabox script from scratch to better understand both Wordpress and PHP.

I'm having some problems with a for each loop on a multidimensional array though. I'm using PHP5.

This is the array:

```
$meta_box = array();    
$meta_box[] = array(
            'id' => 'monitor-specs',
            'title' => 'Monitor Specifications',
            'context' => 'normal',
            'priority' => 'default',
            'pages' => array('monitors', 'products'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Brand',
                    'desc' => 'Enter the brand of the monitor.',
                    'id' => $prefix . 'monitor_brand',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'std' => ''
                )
            )
        );
```

And this is the for each loop:

```
foreach ($meta_box['pages'] as $post_type => $value) {
            add_meta_box($value['id'], $value['title'], 'je_format_metabox', $post_type, $value['context'], $value['priority']);
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the keys in the 'pages' array which is an array inside the 'meta_box' array and at the same time be able to use the key values of the 'meta_box' array.

Do I need to nest some for each loops?

Would be grateful for some pointers in the right direction so I can solve this.

Comment: What do you want to do with those items in pages?

Comment: In case $meta_box has described array, you will get $post_type 0,1 and empty $value['context'], $value['priority']. But in your way should be empty array because $meta_box['pages'] is empty

Comment: `to better understand both Wordpress and PHP.` [rant]Wordpress isn't the best code out there to learn from[/rant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($meta_box[0]['pages'] as $post_type => $value) {
```

or

```
$meta_box = array(...
```

Comment: This answer along with the one from @ajreal helped me solve it! I ended up using `$meta_box = array(...`

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` starts with `$meta_box['pages']`, but there is no `$meta_box['pages']`.

You do have a `$meta_box[0]['pages']` though, so you need two loops:

```
foreach($meta_box as $i => $box)
    foreach($box['pages'] as $page)
        add_meta_box(.., ..); // do whatever
```

What were you expecting to be in your `$value` variable?

Answer (score 1):

this here:

```
$meta_box = array();    
$meta_box[] = array(......
```

suggests that there is no $meta_box['pages']. meta_box is an array with numerical indexes (check the [] operator) and each of its elements is an array that has the key 'pages'.

so you need to use foreach on $meta_box, and on each element you need to use the pages key.. id, title, context are elements on the same level as pages, as you can see

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing to the wrong array key

```
$meta_box[] <-- $meta_box[0]
```

But, you refer using :-

```
foreach ($meta_box['pages'] as $post_type => $value) {
```

Add the array key will solve the problem :-

```
foreach ($meta_box[0]['pages'] as $post_type => $value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be nice to create some class to hold this information.

```
class Metabox
{
  public $id, $title, $context, $priority, $pages, $fields;

  public function __construct($id, $title, $pages, $fiels, $context='normal', $priority='default')
  {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->pages = $pages;
    $this->fields = $fields;
    $this->context = $context;
    $this->priority = $priority;
  }

}

$meta_box = array();

$meta_box[] = new Metabox(
  'monitor-specs', 
  'Monitor Specifications', 
  array('monitors', 'products'),
  array(
    'name' => 'Brand',
    'desc' => 'Enter the brand of the monitor.',
    'id' => $prefix . 'monitor_brand',
    'type' => 'text',
    'std' => ''
  )
);
```

Now you can loop over the meta_box array like:

```
foreach ($meta_box as $box)
{
  add_meta_box($box->id, $box->title, .. and more)
  // This function could be placed in the metabox object

  /* Say you want to access the pages array : */
  $pages = $box->pages;

  foreach ($pages as $page)
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

Now you still have a loop in a loop, but maybe helps seeing your problem more clearly.

Comment: I so need to learn how to create classes! It's one of those things I can't seem to get my brain to understand... One day hopefully, it makes the code so much simpler and prettier!

Comment: at the place i live in we call such things "banging nails with microscope" :) +1 for good solution anyway